# How best to extract a Pandas column containing lists or tuples into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I accidentally closed this question with a link to the wrong duplicate. Here is the correct one: [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns).

Suppose I have a dataframe of which one column is a list (of a known and identical length) or tuple, for example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
 {'vals': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['e','f','g','h']]}
)
```

ie:

```
    vals
0   [a, b, c, d]
1   [e, f, g, h]
```

I want to extra the values in "vals" into separate named columns. I can do this clumsily by iterating through the rows:

```
for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
   for j in range(0,4):
      df1.loc[i, 'vals_'+j] = df1.loc[i, 'vals'] [j]
```

Result as desired:

```
    vals            vals_0  vals_1  vals_2  vals_3
0   [a, b, c, d]    a       b       c       d 
1   [e, f, g, h]    e       f       g       h
```

Is there a neater (vectorised) way? I tried using [] but I get an error.

```
   for j in range (0,4)
       df1['vals_'+str(j)] = df1['vals'][j]
```

gives:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

It looks like Pandas is trying to apply the [] operator to the series/dataframe rather than the column content.

Comment: `df1.vals.apply(pd.Series)` will get you most of the way there.

Comment: @andrew_reece Is that vectorized though?  He'd have to create 4 different series.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `assign`, `apply`, with `pd.Series`:

```
df1.assign(**df1.vals.apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('val_'))
```

A faster method for more data is to use .values and tolist() with dataframe constructor:

```
df1.assign(**pd.DataFrame(df1.vals.values.tolist()).add_prefix('val_'))
```

Output:

```
           vals val_0 val_1 val_2 val_3
0  [a, b, c, d]     a     b     c     d
1  [e, f, g, h]     e     f     g     h
```

Comment: woah, nice kwarg-fu @Scott Boston!

Comment: The way the second method does everything including the column rename fast and in one line is great.

Answer (score 5):

You can apply the `Series` initializer to `vals`, and then [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) to get the column names you're looking for.  Then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to the original for the desired output:

```
pd.concat([df1.vals, df1.vals.apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("vals_")], axis=1)

           vals vals_0 vals_1 vals_2 vals_3
0  [a, b, c, d]      a      b      c      d
1  [e, f, g, h]      e      f      g      h
```