# How do I perform One Hot Encoding on lists in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, list

Suppose I have a dataframe of which one column is a list (of a unknown values and length) for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
 {'messageLabels': [['Good', 'Other', 'Bad'],['Bad','Terrible']]}
)
```

I came across this solution but it isnt what I am looking for.
[How best to extract a Pandas column containing lists or tuples into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999418/how-best-to-extract-a-pandas-column-containing-lists-or-tuples-into-multiple-col)

in theory the resulting df would look like

```
messageLabels             | Good| Other| Bad| Terrible
--------------------------------------------------------
['Good', 'Other', 'Bad']  | True| True |True| False
--------------------------------------------------------
['Bad','Terrible']        |False|False |True| True
```

See above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way is to use the apply and the Series constructor:

```
In [11]: pd.get_dummies(df.messageLabels.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1, x)) == 1)
Out[11]:
    Good  Other   Bad  Terrible
0   True   True  True     False
1  False  False  True      True
```

where

```
In [12]: df.messageLabels.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1, x))
Out[12]:
   Good  Other  Bad  Terrible
0   1.0    1.0  1.0       NaN
1   NaN    NaN  1.0       1.0
```

---

To get your desired output:

```
In [21]: res = pd.get_dummies(df.messageLabels.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1, x)) == 1)

In [22]: df[res.columns] = res

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
        messageLabels   Good  Other   Bad  Terrible
0  [Good, Other, Bad]   True   True  True     False
1     [Bad, Terrible]  False  False  True      True
```

Comment: Heh!  and explain this `pd.get_dummies(df.messageLabels.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(True, x)))`

Comment: @piRSquared so you can do this without the get_dummies using  `df.messageLabels.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(True, x)).fillna(False)`

Comment: I added a version of that in my post.  `dict.fromkeys`

Answer (score 6):

#### Succint

```
df.join(df.messageLabels.str.join('|').str.get_dummies().astype(bool))

        messageLabels   Bad   Good  Other  Terrible
0  [Good, Other, Bad]  True   True   True     False
1     [Bad, Terrible]  True  False  False      True
```

---

#### `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
dum = mlb.fit_transform(df.messageLabels)

df.join(pd.DataFrame(dum.astype(bool), df.index, mlb.classes_))

        messageLabels   Bad   Good  Other  Terrible
0  [Good, Other, Bad]  True   True   True     False
1     [Bad, Terrible]  True  False  False      True
```

---

#### Overdone

```
n = len(df)
i = np.arange(n)
l = [*map(len, df.messageLabels)]
j, u = pd.factorize(np.concatenate(df.messageLabels))

o = np.zeros((n, len(u)), bool)
o[i.repeat(l), j] = True

df.join(pd.DataFrame(o, df.index, u))

        messageLabels   Good  Other   Bad  Terrible
0  [Good, Other, Bad]   True   True  True     False
1     [Bad, Terrible]  False  False  True      True
```

---

#### Messing around

And inspire by [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56299184/2336654)

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame([dict.fromkeys(x, True) for x in df.messageLabels]).fillna(False))

        messageLabels   Bad   Good  Other  Terrible
0  [Good, Other, Bad]  True   True   True     False
1     [Bad, Terrible]  True  False  False      True
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using `get_dummies` and `sum` (or `max`, either of them work):

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame(df['messageLabels'].tolist())
pd.get_dummies(tmp, prefix='', prefix_sep='').max(level=0, axis=1).astype(bool)

    Bad   Good  Other  Terrible
0  True   True   True     False
1  True  False  False      True
```

You can combine this with `df` using `join`:

```
df.join(pd.get_dummies(tmp, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
          .max(level=0, axis=1)
          .astype(bool))

        messageLabels   Bad   Good  Other  Terrible
0  [Good, Other, Bad]  True   True   True     False
1     [Bad, Terrible]  True  False  False      True
```

---

You can also `stack` and `pivot_table`:

```
(pd.DataFrame(df['messageLabels'].tolist())
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
   .pivot_table(index='level_0', columns=0, aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
   .astype(bool))

0         Bad   Good  Other  Terrible
level_0                              
0        True   True   True     False
1        True  False  False      True
```